# Is there a chart/listener in JMeter that would show data of different runs in same graph?

Tags: jmeter

I have measured separately our application server CPU with 5 users and 15 users. Both runs took 5 minutes. I would like to show both runs and CPU in one graph. Currently the only way to do it is to export CSV to Excel and create custom graphs. This is silly because the graphs are quite good in JMeter itself.

JMeter plugin extensions contains a graph called Composite graph, but the use-case seems to be to be able to add many data points to one and the same graph from within the same run. It doesn't seem to be able to merge graphs from two separate thread runs because the time in the two are different (the two runs have been executed in succession and therefore the graphs are shown after one-another, not at the same time).

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it can be done using the information here [jmeter_wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JtlFiles) but that it will still require some effort.